# Why is the canonical formulation of a dual basis actually a basis of the dual space?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $B=\{v_{i}\}$ be the basis for $V$, and $B^{*}=\{f_{i}\}$ be our basis for $V^{*}$.  The typical formulation of $B^{*}$ is:

$$f_{i}(v_{j}) = \delta_{j}^{i} = 1 \textrm{ (if i = j), otherwise } = 0$$

However, I'm having a hard time understand why exactly this is a basis of $V^{*}$.  That is, suppose I have a new linear functional $f'$  that I want to represent as a linear combination of dual basis vectors.  How would I do so?  How do I show they are linearly independent & span $V^{*}$? I have a feeling this is very simple, but I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around it.

Comment: The picture to have in mind is that if $V$ is a vector space of $n \times 1$ matrices, then $V^*$ is a vector space of $1 \times n$ matrices. The standard bases on both are the vectors that have a $1$ in one position and $0$ in the others. (and these bases are dual)

Comment: Thanks, this ^ is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Suppose you want 
  $$
  f'=\sum b_jf_j
  $$
  Evaluating at $v_i$ on both sides, you have a linear equation on the coefficients $b_i$.
- To show the linear independence of $\{f_j\}$, write
  $$
  \sum b_jf_j=0.
  $$
  You want to show $b_j=0$. But the right hand side is the zero function on $V$. What do you get by taking the action on ${v_i}$ on both sides?

Comment: Lots of editing going on here haha... thanks for the answer, looking over it.

Comment: Hmmm, I see, so each $f'(v_{j})$ just ends up equally $b_{i}$.  For the second bullet, you get that each $b_{j} = $.  Damn, I get it, still a little abstract but I'll keep mulling over it.  Thanks.

Comment: You might find the Wikipedia article on [dual basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_basis) be useful.